# Подскажите алгоритм для быстрого подсчета количества пересечений отрезков на прямой

Tags: python, алгоритм

```py
n = int(input())
segments = []

for i in range(n):
    l, r = map(int, input().split())
    segments.append((l, r))

def is_intersection(seg1, seg2):
    return max(seg1[0], seg2[0]) <= min(seg1[1], seg2[1])

intersection_count = [0] * n

for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n):
        if i != j and is_intersection(segments[i], segments[j]):
            intersection_count[i] += 1

print(*intersection_count)
```

В кратце, весь код работает как надо, единственная проблема - это время. Нужно сократить время выполнения программы до 2-х секунд. Заранее спасибо

Comment: Пожалуйста, добавьте в вопрос задачу, которую вы решаете, ограничения на память, ссылку на проверяющую систему и описание вашего алгоритма.

Comment: А вообще почитайте про заметание.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Что такое _заметание_?

Comment: @Vitalizzare, сейчас допишу ответ и узнаете.

Answer (score 3):

Возьмём отрезок *s*. Cо сколькими своими собратьями он пересекается? Все пересечения можно разбить на две группы. Первая: отрезки, которые начались раньше начала *s* и ещё не закончились. Вторая: отрезки, которые начались между началом и концом *s*.

Ещё раз. Пусть *f(x)* - число отрезков, у которых начало *≤ x*. Пусть *g(x)* - число отрезков, у которых конец *< x*. Пусть *s = [a, b]* - отрезок. Тогда число пересечений отрезка *s* равно:

*(f(a) - 1 - g(a)) + (f(b) - f(a)) = f(b) - g(a) - 1*

Первое слагаемое - число отрезков начавшихся до *a* и ещё не завершившихся. Минус единица нужна чтобы исключить из суммы сам отрезок *s*. Второе слагаемое - число отрезков, начавшихся между в полуинтервале *(a, b]*.

Решать задачу будем заметанием по *x*. События - начала и концы отрезков. Начало отрезка увеличивает *f* (в коде это переменная `starts`), конец отрезка увеличивает *g* (в коде это переменная `ends`). Если у нескольких отрезков совпадают начала, порядок обработки событий не важен. Если совпадают концы, тоже. Если в одной точке есть и начала и концы, все начала обрабатываются до всех концов. При обработке начала конкретного отрезка в счётчик пересечений записывается текущее `-ends`. При обработке конца к нему добавляется текущее `starts - 1`.

Сложность *O(NlogN)*:

```
n = int(input())

events = []
for i in range(n):
    start, end = map(int, input().split())
    events.append((start, False, i))
    events.append((end  , True , i))

events.sort()

starts = 0
ends = 0
intersections = [None] * n

for x, f, i in events:
    if f:  # end
        intersections[i] += starts - 1
        ends += 1
    else:  # start
        intersections[i] = -ends
        starts += 1

print(*intersections)
```

Comment: Да, это хорошо. Скромный вопрос: почему бы не переименовать `f` так чтобы эта переменная легче считывалась? Я бы и `None` заменил на ноль. Не принципиально, но глаз цепляется и невольно задаешься вопросом "Почему `None`?"

Comment: Спасибо, что предложили правку. `is_end` легче читается чем `f`. Но я не использую распространённые имена переменных в циклах. Код некрасиво расплывается. `None` - средство отладки. Если я сделаю ошибку в индексации `intersections`, сразу будет видно. Но это тоже обсуждается: ради отладки нарушена  типизация. Можно было бы: `[-1] * n`, `-= ends`, `+= starts`.
Так или иначе, мы обсуждаем частности, а важен алгоритм - то самое заметание.

Answer (score 1):

```
def count_intersections(segments):

    from itertools import chain
    
    count = [0]*len(segments)
    seq = [*chain(*segments)]
    segments = [k//2 for k in sorted(range(len(seq)), 
                                     key=lambda k: (seq[k], k&1))]
    stack = set()
    for s in segments:
        try:
            stack.remove(s)
        except KeyError:
            for k in stack:
                count[k] += 1
            count[s] = len(stack)
            stack.add(s)
    return count
```

Скорость этого алгоритма определяется скоростью сортировки, скоростью доступа к элементам множества и уровнем связанности отрезков между собой. В крайнем случае, когда всё пересекается со всем, например `segments = [*zip(range(100), repeat(100))]`, сложность можно оценить как *O(n²)*. Другая крайность - это когда пересечения отсутствуют или же их количество ограничено числом, не зависящим от количества отрезков. В этом случае сложность вычислений определяется алгоритмом сортировки.

Как работает алгоритм? Сначала мы выстравиваем числа, указывающие на концы отрезков, в одну последовательность. Например, отрезки `[(5, 7), (1, 3), (2, 6)]` преобразуется в список `[5, 7, 1, 3, 2, 6]`, где начала отрезков стоят на четных позициях, а концы - на нечетных.

Дальше мы сортируем числа, но в итоговом списке ставим вместо них номер соответствующего отрезка (чтобы узнать, к какому отрезку принадлежит число, мы делим его исходную позицию на 2). Дополнение `k&1` нужно для того, чтобы в случае, когда начало одного отрезка совпадает с концом другого, индекс начала разположился *перед* индексом конца, и тогда отрезки будут учитываться как пересекающиеся (но если мы рассматриваем отрезки как открытые, то `k&1` нужно заменить на `~k&1`) Продолжая предыдущий пример, последовательность чисел `[5, 7, 1, 3, 2, 6]` преобразуется в последовательность индексов отрезков `[1, 2, 1, 0, 2, 0]`

После этого проходим полученную последовательно индексов исходных отрезков слева направо, наполняя ими стек по мере появления новых отрезков и опустошая стек при достижении концов. Отрезки, находящиеся в теке, между собой пересекаются. Соответственно каждый новый отрезок увеличивает счетчик пересечений находящихся в стеке отрезков на единицу, а количество находящихся в стеке отрезков является исходним значением счетчика для нового добавляемого отрезка.

Тест-кейсы:

```
segments = [(0, 1), (2, 3), (4, 5)]
assert count_intersections(segments) == [0, 0, 0]

segments = [(0, 2), (1, 3)]
assert count_intersections(segments) == [1, 1]

segments = [(0, 5), (1, 4), (2, 3)]
assert count_intersections(segments) == [2, 2, 2]

segments = [(0, 1)]
assert count_intersections(segments) == [0]

segments = [(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4)]
assert count_intersections(segments) == [1, 2, 1]

segments = [(2, 3), (3, 4), (1, 2)]
assert count_intersections(segments) == [2, 1, 1]
```

Сравним производительность:

```
def count_intersections_OP(segments):
    "Исходный алгорим подсчета количества пересечений отрезков"

    def is_intersection(seg1, seg2):
        return max(seg1[0], seg2[0]) <= min(seg1[1], seg2[1])

    n = len(segments)
    intersection_count = [0] * n

    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(n):
            if i != j and is_intersection(segments[i], segments[j]):
                intersection_count[i] += 1
                
    return intersection_count


def get_short_segments(N=10_000, start=0, stop=1_000, max_length=50):
    from random import randint
    left = [randint(start, stop) for _ in range(N)]
    length = [randint(1, max_length) for _ in range(N)]
    return [(left, left+length) for left, length in zip(left, length)]

loops, time = Timer(
    'count_intersections_OP(segments)', 
    setup='segments=get_short_segments()', 
    globals=globals()).autorange()
print('Average (original):', time/loops)

loops, time = Timer(
    'count_intersections(segments)', 
    setup='segments=get_short_segments()', 
    globals=globals()).autorange()
print('Average (new):', time/loops)
```

Результат на моей машине:

```
Average (original): 53.4831825819856
Average (new): 0.23387293799896725
```

Тест на вложенных друг в друга отрезках:

```
from itertools import repeat
    
segments = [*zip(range(5_000), repeat(5_000))]

loops, time = Timer(
    'count_intersections_OP(segments)', 
    globals=globals()).autorange()
print('Average (original):', time/loops)

loops, time = Timer(
    'count_intersections(segments)', 
    globals=globals()).autorange()
print('Average (new):', time/loops)
```

Мой результат:

```
Average (original): 14.986755997000728
Average (new): 0.8407918120210525
```

Comment: Вам не кажется, что алгоритм квадратичный? Например, на наборе [1,101],[2,102]...[100,200] первый счётчик будет инкрементирован 99 раз, второй 98 и т.д.